# Button click faking

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to make my mobile web app appear more responsive. So when you click an icon that's an image i want to use jquery mobile to whilst it's being clicked show a different image (different colour) to make it appear that somethings been done, then when you let go it should change back.

I'm trying the following but it doesn't appear to be firing. Anyone have any tips?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.homeAlerts').on( "vmousedown", "a", function() {
        console.log("Clicked");
        $('#homeAlerts').attr('src','mages/HomeIcons/typeOneClicked_0003_Alerts');

    });


    $('.homeAlerts').on( "vmouseup", "a", function() {
        $('#homeAlerts').attr('src','mages/HomeIcons/typeOne_0003_Alerts.png');
    });

});
```

Markup

```
   <div class="iconL">
                        <a href="#alerts" class="homeAlerts">
                            <img id="homeAlerts" src="images/HomeIcons/typeOne_0003_Alerts.png" />
                            <center class="pullup">Alerts</center>
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

Comment: `$("a.homeAlerts").on(........)`. Edit: Dont use `.ready()` in jQM, use [page events](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/).

Comment: There is no anchor tag wrapped inside any `.homeAlerts` element in your posted HTML markup

Comment: homeAlerts is anchor tag though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jquery mousedown and mouseup functions instead:

```
 $("img#homeAlerts").mousedown(function(){
      $(this).attr("src", "images/HomeIcons/typeOneClicked_0003_Alerts.png")
 });
 $("img#homeAlerts").mouseup(function(){
      $(this).attr("src", "images/HomeIcons/typeOne_0003_Alerts.png")
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

to answer your original question, pretty sure you should be doing:

```
$('#homeAlerts').on( "vmousedown", "a", function() {
    console.log("Clicked");
    $(this).attr('src','mages/HomeIcons/typeOneClicked_0003_Alerts');

});


$('#homeAlerts').on( "vmouseup", "a", function() {
    $(this).attr('src','mages/HomeIcons/typeOne_0003_Alerts.png');
});
```

(your selector is trying to select a class, but you have an id on your image)